# Insert full width block inside grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm creating a page layout that Google Images has some time ago. There is a grid of images with large full with section under selected image. And I'm curious is it possible to mark up this page with css `disaply: grid` property.

[image: grid page template]

At first I made container with three columns. Everything is great:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div>  
</div>
```

But I have no idea, how to insert description block inside this grid. I'm not sure is it possible at all. I'm going to toggle descriptions via `display: none | block`. The number of images and rows is unknown.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}

.item__description {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__description">Description of the first item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the last item. No matter where to place this description: inside or outside 'item' block</div>
</div>
```

The idea is to create this layout without any js DOM manipulations.

Comment: I tried this a few months ago - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zWgjgW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` on the `.container`. Move the `.item__description` outside of item, and set `grid-column: 1 / span 3;` on it.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}

.item__description {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the first item</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the last item. No matter where to place this description: inside or outside 'item' block</div>
</div>
```

This will also work with display toggling (hover an item):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}

.item__description {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}

.item:hover + .item__description {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hover Me 1</div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Hover Me 2</div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Hover Me 3</div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Hover Me 4</div>
  <div class="item__description">Description of the item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Additionally, `grid-column: 1 / span 3;` means start on column 1 and take up 3 columns. Likewise `grid-column: span 3;` means start anywhere but span 3 columns (which would also work in this example). If you omit `span` then it means end on the 3rd column, regardless of where it started.

Comment: These full span rows can leave gaps on previous rows. `grid-auto-flow: ... dense;` means the grid can backfill those gaps with future items (if they fit).

Comment: Or... if you do not know the amount of columns use `grid-column: 1 / -1;`